# Parse Cannot login with Facebook after logging out, unless app is force-quit

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In our appDelegate file we perform a logout method

```
-(void)logoutUser
{
  if([PFUser currentUser]){

    [FBSession.activeSession close];
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];

    [[PFFacebookUtils session] close];

    [PFUser logOut];

    //Check the session is properly gone (All return null, so we're all clear and logged out)
    NSLog(@"User is %@", [PFUser currentUser]);
    NSLog(@"Facebook session is %@", [PFFacebookUtils session]);
    NSLog(@"Facebook session is %@", FBSession.activeSession.observationInfo);

    //load the story board
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];

    // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
    UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
    self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;


    }
}
```

This sets the storyboard as our Login view, but if you try to login again it's not working. It will take you to the Facebook app/Safari based on whatever you have setup, but when it returns to our App nothing occurs.

This block never gets called:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

    if (user) {

        [self loginWithFB];
    }
    else {

        MLog(@"error %@",error.localizedDescription);
        [_progressBar hide:YES];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error" message:@"The app can not connect with Facebook." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Login error %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

}];
```

But if you Force-Quit the app, it gets called like normal and login works a treat.

**Edit:**
Pretty sure this is a Parse SDK bug, due to be fixed. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/994229510592686/

Comment: Could you post the Login View method containing the logInWithPermissions: line? If it never even gets called, the reason definitely lies in the code surrounding it.

Comment: Hi @LyndseyScott, I've added my loginWithPermissions for you. Thanks

Comment: You'd have to add the whole method containing loginWithPermissions. Like I said, if it never even gets called, the reason definitely lies in the code surrounding it.

Comment: My Mistake, here's a link to the entire loginVC.m file:
http://pastebin.com/6aRHY4ZM

Comment: So you're tapping a button to trigger your login? And no error prints out, right?

Comment: Oh, I see a big problem... To make both transitions you're initializing your rootViewController to contain the initial view of your storyboard. Definitely not right on several accounts...

Comment: You mean because I'm using `instantiateInitialViewController`?

Comment: That in combination with repeatedly setting your root view controller. But why do you think logInWithPermissions isn't being called? What happens when you put a breakpoint or NSLog in it?

Comment: To clarify it is called, it will break, but normally you would play through it once, when Facebook responds it would break again, and with a User object. In our situation it just simply doesn't return any data.